# stabilityai/stable-diffusion-2-1-base does not appear to have a file named scheduler_config.json

Tags: huggingface-transformers, stable-diffusion, diffusers

```
python preprocess.py --data_path data/horse.jpg --inversion_prompt 'A black horse runs in the sand'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 203, in _new_conn
    sock = connection.create_connection(
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 73, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 491, in _make_request
    raise new_e
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 467, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1092, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 611, in connect
    self.sock = sock = self._new_conn()
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 218, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f549f79bac0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 844, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 515, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingface.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /stabilityai/stable-diffusion-2-1-base/resolve/main/scheduler/scheduler_config.json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f549f79bac0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/huggingface_hub/file_download.py", line 1230, in hf_hub_download
    metadata = get_hf_file_metadata(
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/huggingface_hub/utils/_validators.py", line 118, in _inner_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/huggingface_hub/file_download.py", line 1597, in get_hf_file_metadata
    r = _request_wrapper(
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/huggingface_hub/file_download.py", line 417, in _request_wrapper
    response = _request_wrapper(
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/huggingface_hub/file_download.py", line 452, in _request_wrapper
    return http_backoff(
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/huggingface_hub/utils/_http.py", line 258, in http_backoff
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/huggingface_hub/utils/_http.py", line 63, in send
    return super().send(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 519, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: (MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='huggingface.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /stabilityai/stable-diffusion-2-1-base/resolve/main/scheduler/scheduler_config.json (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f549f79bac0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable'))"), '(Request ID: 2f730fc3-1e28-4315-968f-c892e0adf0fe)')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/diffusers/configuration_utils.py", line 358, in load_config
    config_file = hf_hub_download(
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/huggingface_hub/utils/_validators.py", line 118, in _inner_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/huggingface_hub/file_download.py", line 1347, in hf_hub_download
    raise LocalEntryNotFoundError(
huggingface_hub.utils._errors.LocalEntryNotFoundError: An error happened while trying to locate the file on the Hub and we cannot find the requested files in the local cache. Please check your connection and try again or make sure your Internet connection is on.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data1/wz/research/pnp-diffusers-main/preprocess.py", line 220, in <module>
    run(opt)
  File "/data1/wz/research/pnp-diffusers-main/preprocess.py", line 183, in run
    toy_scheduler = DDIMScheduler.from_pretrained(model_key, subfolder="scheduler")
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/diffusers/schedulers/scheduling_utils.py", line 140, in from_pretrained
    config, kwargs, commit_hash = cls.load_config(
  File "/data1/wz/anaconda3/envs/pnp-diffusers/lib/python3.9/site-packages/diffusers/configuration_utils.py", line 385, in load_config
    raise EnvironmentError(
OSError: stabilityai/stable-diffusion-2-1-base does not appear to have a file named scheduler_config.json.
```

How do I solve this problem?

I tried

```
pip install --upgrade transformers,
```

however, it did not work.

Comment: What is the version of your `transformers` and `diffusers`? You can check it in the terminal via `pip show package_name`.

Comment: Thank you answer, my transformers==4.30.2, and my diffusers==0.17.1. could you help me solve this question? I tried many methods but it did not work. the program I run is https://github.com/MichalGeyer/pnp-diffusers

Comment: I have another question, is this problem related to the network?

Comment: Most likely an invalid url issue. It's searching for the file under: `https://huggingface.co/stabilityai/stable-diffusion-2-1-base/resolve/main/scheduler/` but the actual url seems [this](https://huggingface.co/stabilityai/stable-diffusion-2-1/blob/main/scheduler/scheduler_config.json) one.

Comment: But your libraries seem outdated as well. Can you upgrade to the latest `transformers` (==4.33.2) and `diffusers` (==0.21.2) libraries and check if that resolves the issue? Also upgrade your `urllib` as well.

Comment: Thank you answer, I tried this method but doesn't work. I don't know why,maybe is internet connect

Answer (score -1):

Simply typing huggingface-cli login and entering a token on the command line solves this problem